# Elegant way of handling similar code

Tags: c++, git, code-organization, pragma

I have a software project that is working just fine.
Now, this project has to be adjusted to model a new, but related system.
What strategies are there to keep these two codes well organized?
They will have a codebase that is about 90% the same, but there are many functions which need slight adjustments.

I have thought of the following:

1. Different branches in the git-repository: perfect control of the two projects, but common changes have to be made in each of the branches separately.
2. Modelling different program modes by C++ pragmas (#ifdef Project1 ...):
   this keeps the changes local, but makes the code difficult to read.

I am not too satisfied by these solutions. Is there a better approach?

Comment: An alternative to lots of `#ifdef`s is a link time seam. You have a .cpp that you compile and link to on Windows and a different one that you compile and link to on Linux, for example.

Comment: If the differences fit into well-defined areas, you could consider defining interface and using classes to hide the implementation detail - a bit like drivers do, but the concept can be applied more widely.

Comment: Did you thought about moving all common code to the static library. And your apps will call functions/create objects with params that make difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have same problem and here is how we solve it:

- We have only one branch on our git repo
- Beside common files, we have different files according configuration: access_for_config1.cpp, access_for_config2.cpp, ...
- We use *design pattern* like *factory* to abstract specific part for common part
- For small very specific parts on common files, we have a `#ifdef` section according configuration
- We have different rules in our makefile according each configuration: for a configuration, we compile common file + specific file and set correct flag. Also, using eclipse at office, we also define different build configuration, to allow correct highlighting.

Advantage of this approach is to keep common part always synchronous, and we isolate correctly each specific parts.

But, you have to be careful with not so far piece of code from each configuration. For example, with similar (but not same) code in different specific files, possible bug can be corrected in only one configuration. It can be reduce by defining some piece of code as common template or by re-thinking design to put some part in common

Hope it's answer will help you

Answer (score 1):

> What strategies are there to keep these two codes well organized? They will have a codebase that is about 90% the same

---

Its not exactly what you need but just make sure you know about it.

> ***`Submodules`*** ***allow foreign repositories to be embedded within a dedicated subdirectory*** of the source tree, always pointed at a particular commit.

---

> Different branches in the git-repository: perfect control of the two projects, but common changes have to be made in each of the branches separately.

You can commit changes to one branch and then use cherry-pick to add them to any other branch you want.